# Redirect url internally but keep entered URL

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have the following code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^p/(.*)$ /p.php?id=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Functionally speaking, the code above works. But the URL changes from `p/X` to `p.php?id=X`. I suspect the problem lies in the values between [], and I've tried different values, watching other questions on the same object, but no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1):

Remove `R` flag since that causes external redirection in browser.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+p\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /p/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^p/(.+)$ /p.php?id=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Also note disabling of `MultiViews` option. Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs before `mod_rewrite` and and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.

Also added `QSA` flag. `QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one.

#### References:

- [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite Technical Details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite In-Depth Details](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708)